# RPC Broadcasting server isnt working

Tags: c, rpc

I'm currently working on **RPC based single sender multiple receiver system**. I need to use RPC only.

I have created RCP broadcaster, and it works perfectly nice.
I can use *tshark* on other systems and they showed they received a RPC message from source 10.9.9.3 to destination 10.9.9.255.

So, it seems my broadcasting client works.

At receiving end nothing happens really.

I'll list up all the function calls I made in RPC broadcast receiver:

```
SVCXPRT * transp;
pmap_unset(prog,vers);
transp=svcudp_create(RPC_ANYSOCK);
svc_register(transp,prog,vers,rpc_listener,IPPROTO_UDP);
svc_run();
```

Of course I've added all error checking. I haven't add them to make it simpler.
And in my rpc_listener function, I'm just printing that This function is called.
But nothing ever happens.
RPC broadcast listener start, prints all debug information that I put to make sure prog and vers are correct and then goes into svc_run, and never execute rpc_listener function.

One to one  communication works nice, but broadcasting doest work.
Am I missing Something?
Did I miss any steps in getting the system ready to receive the broadcast?

**Update:**
Rather than using RPC_ANYSOCK, I even tried to create a UDP socket and then use setsockopt with flag SO_BROADCAST. But result is still the same.

Comment: I assume, your client uses UDP as well

Comment: @tigran: If you are talking about broadcast client, then Yes. RPC broadcast works on UDP only.

Comment: could you check the return code of svc_register?

Comment: @tigran: As I have said earlier, I have done all error checking, and from client or server side none gives any error. rpcinfo shows my application binding as well. the version and program number are perfect, yet somehow application doesn't receive message. Only thing I can think of is that the destination add of broadcasted rpc message is 10.9.9.255 while my listeners IP is 10.9.9.2.

Comment: Really? No body ever worked on RPC broadcasting?

Comment: Did you check that with direct request works? And check firewall settings.